# Google Cloud Dataproc Initialization Scripts for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Google Cloud Dataproc [provides initialization scripts](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions) for many frameworks, including Kafka, Zeppelin etc, there is no default script for Cassandra, was wondering if there is one scripted already by any.

Thanks

Comment: Asking for off site resources is considered off topic for Stackoverflow, but I would suggest searching elsewhere for Terraform or Ansible Cassandra setups

Comment: The DataProc is managed Hadoop Cluster, using Terraform or Ansible will be like you are running your own, and they are easy to write as you don't need knowledge about Data Proc, hence I posted the above question. Any how I get your point, thanks.

Comment: I feel like you answered your own question. Managed **Hadoop**. Cassandra is a completely different product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my humble point of view, initialization actions install lightweight services in most of the cases, like libraries or clients, tools that don't require much resources. Otherwise, it can cause a poor performance of jobs executed in Dataproc cluster.

You can [install Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/getting_started/installing.html) on a single node without needing an init action, e.g. in one node of a Dataproc cluster, but for [advanced installations](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/initialize/initializeSingleDS.html), I think it is better to create a separate set of instances.

Comment: As HBase has scripts, I was looking in similar way, I think you are right considering that most use cases are ephimeral,  not really used for storage as such.